# List of values I can specify in Zend application.ini configuration file?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration

I am using the Zend Framework and I cannot locate in the documentation the values I can specify in the application.ini file. Does anyone have a link to where I could see them?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exhaustive list, since you can specify arbitrary configuration values that are specific to your app.

The "built-in" stuff is mostly about configuting build-in resource plugins, so a good source of information on those might help you.  The manual [describes them](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) in fair detail.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was looking in the wrong area. Thanks again :).