# Zend Framework : Need All parameters for application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know all the parameters/options which can be used in application.ini file. Is there any list available?

Please help

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136337/list-of-values-i-can-specify-in-zend-application-ini-configuration-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify anything you want. For instance, I set my javascript files there:

```
js.jquery.filename = "/js/jquery.min.js"
js.jquery.offset = 0
js.jqueryui.filename = "/js/jquery-ui.min.js"
js.jqueryui.offset = 1
js.nestedsortable.filename = '/js/jquery.ui.nestedSortable.js'
js.nestedsortable.offset = 2
js.ckeditor.filename = "/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
js.ckeditor.offset = 3
```

Now, whenever I need to add a javascript file, I do:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
$js = $config['js'];
$this->view->headScript()->offsetSetFile($js['ckeditor']['offset'],$js['ckeditor']['filename']);
$this->view->headScript()->offsetSetFile($js['jquery']['offset'],$js['jquery']['filename']);
```

Like I said, you can specify any value. Anything you will be accessing often and need to be available globally can and perhaps should be there :).

Answer (score 0):

During loading config in `index.php` you can store it in `Zend_Registry` and you can access them when you want.

You can also parse `Zend_Config` to an array and look, what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

@Future King Do this:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
Zend_Debug::dump($config);
```

That should do it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Provided that the config was actually saved in `Zend_Registry`, probably during `Bootstrap`.